# Unable to start client using ssh in python

Tags: python, sockets, ssh

I'm developting a automation framework with little manual intervention. There is one server and client

what server does is it sends some command to client and get the output.

To start the socket connection with client machine i'm using Spur module in server machine itself (rather than going into each client and executing client program).

what is happening is the it is able to establish the connection and send to the client but not able to receive anything from client

server.py

```
import socket

serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
print host
port = 11111
serversock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversock.bind((host,port))
serversock.listen(4)

try:
    csock,addr = serversock.accept()
    print 'Recieved address from %s '% str(addr)
    print csock.send('hello') **# It is able to print the number of bytes sent**
    data = csock.recv(1024)  
    print data                 **# But not receiving any data**
    csock.close()

except Exception,e:
    print e
```

Here is the spur module program. Right now running it separately but has to be in the server.py itself. so, in server machine I am running server program and this spur module program.

```
import spur
ss = spur.SshShell(hostname = "172.16.6.58",username ='username',password = 'password',shell_type=spur.ssh.ShellTypes.minimal,missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
res = ss.run(['python', '/home/some_username/clientsock.py'])
print res.output
```

Here is the client program which is running on 172.16.6.58 machine (which we ssh ing to)

clientsock.py

```
import socket

try:
    c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    host = '172.16.6.32'
    port = 11111
    c.connect((host,port))
    data = c.recv(1024)
    print data
    msg = 'hi this is client'
    c.send(msg)

except Exception,e:
    print e


finally:
    c.close()
```

Please tell what is wrong with this code or which module should I use to start a process in client machine?

Comment: You could use Popen to run your ssh commands. It's just a recommendation since I have no idea what Spur is but I'm guessing that's what it uses anyway.

Comment: I would consider using fabric, or maybe even ansible